# Logout / Signout link for Azure based web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, forms-authentication

I am very new to Windows Azure. We have developed one web application and deployed in Azure. We are in need to include "Sign out / Logout" link in this app. By googling, I tried with following commands

WSFederationAuthenticationModule fam = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
 FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
 fam.SignOut(true);

However, it is not help for me.

Could you please give me some ideas to implement any one of "Sign out / Log out / Sign in different user"?

Comment: if your application is simple web app, then it is not related to Azure. What authentication mechanism you are using in your application?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Yes, it is simple web app, and I have used "Azure authentication mechanism"

Comment: What did you choose when creating the project? Cloud - Single organization? Or different cloud auth option?